# iOS SDWebImage NSURLErrorDomain error 406 before it even contacts the server, why?

Tags: ios, web-services, url, sdwebimage

I have written a WS and one of the things it provides is avatars(uploading and servering). The only problem is that any time I try to access one with SDWebImage (UIButton+SDWebImage) I get the above error in my completion handler. Complete error is: (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=406 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 406.)" ) 
The weird thing about it is that the server isn't ever getting touched (put logging in to verify this)! Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

PS If I NSLog the URL and then copy and paste it into a browser it works perfectly, so it's something with SDWebImage or iOS.

**EDIT** Code in question:

```
[btn setBackgroundImageWithURL:url forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-empty.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"error loading image:%@",error);
                        return;
                    }
                    NSLog(@"image should be loaded");
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [btn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                    });
                }];
```

As for the URL I would rather not share it as we don't have a domain name at the moment and I don't want to give out the ip of my client's server... I'm sure you understand, but here is the url minus the correct ip(note that I had to add the spaces to post the edits, they aren't in the actual url):
http:// 192 .168 .1 .21/uploads/51078f979c966bde0b000009/avatar.png

Could it be something with my WS? something about the headers or something? I know it's sending back the content type of "image/png" if that helps and like I said it works perfectly in a browser. Could it be the fact that it's an ip instead of a domain name?

**UPDATE** We have gotten the domain name set up and it's still not working so here is a link that will work in a browser, but not SDWebImage or AFNetworking: http://communication.notitlabs.co/uploads/511db303367885c248000015/avatar.png

Comment: Could you show us any code? Hard to understand what is going on without it.

Comment: The URL would be helpful too.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: IIRC, it was an issue with the server sending the image with the wrong mime type. Been 4 years though^^; sorry

Answer (score 3):

If you really have HTTP error 406, [read up on that here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) - sounds like an issue with HTTP headers.

To be sure, though, you need to look at the NSError object's `code` property and match it up with one of these error codes from the [Foundations Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html):

```
   NSURLErrorUnknown = -1,
   NSURLErrorCancelled = -999,
   NSURLErrorBadURL = -1000,
   NSURLErrorTimedOut = -1001,
   NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL = -1002,
   NSURLErrorCannotFindHost = -1003,
   NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004,
   NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum = -1103,
   NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost = -1005,
   NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed = -1006,
   NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects = -1007,
   NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable = -1008,
   NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009,
   NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation = -1010,
   NSURLErrorBadServerResponse = -1011,
   NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication = -1012,
   NSURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired = -1013,
   NSURLErrorZeroByteResource = -1014,
   NSURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData = -1015,
   NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData = -1016,
   NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse = -1017,
   NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff = -1018,
   NSURLErrorCallIsActive = -1019,
   NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed = -1020,
   NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted = -1021,
   NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist = -1100,
   NSURLErrorFileIsDirectory = -1101,
   NSURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile = -1102,
   NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed = -1200,
   NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasBadDate = -1201,
   NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted = -1202,
   NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasUnknownRoot = -1203,
   NSURLErrorServerCertificateNotYetValid = -1204,
   NSURLErrorClientCertificateRejected = -1205,
   NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired = -1206,
   NSURLErrorCannotLoadFromNetwork = -2000,
   NSURLErrorCannotCreateFile = -3000,
   NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile = -3001,
   NSURLErrorCannotCloseFile = -3002,
   NSURLErrorCannotWriteToFile = -3003,
   NSURLErrorCannotRemoveFile = -3004,
   NSURLErrorCannotMoveFile = -3005,
   NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedMidStream = -3006,
   NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedToComplete = -3007
```

Comment: it gets a 406, but like I said it doesn't actually talk to the server... I can get it to work with a different lib... but I would like to stick with SDWebImage because of the cacheing if at all possible.

Comment: If it's not actually talking to the server, then it's not a real 406.  The 406 error would be given from the server.

Comment: that's kinda what I was saying. I think the lib is just killing the request and saying "406", it also happens with AFNetworking, but not with Nimbus or in a browser... it's freaking weird...

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=406 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 406.)"

Comment: Oh, duh, that's what I get for skimming. :)  If it's not connecting to the server, and you're connected to the Internet, then something's wrong with your request.  If you `po [url absoluteString]` do you see what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Just call this code before `.sd_setImage` etc:

```
SDWebImageDownloader.shared().setValue("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Can't tell for sure, but this looks like a bug in SDWebImage? It's kind of weird, because the same code would work for one domain/path, but not another...